# Stop VS Code Debugger From Debugging Third Party Library Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My TS project loads JQuery library code from a CDN. I have set the VS Code debugger to stop at caught & uncaught exceptions, and so the debugger is stopping on exceptions in the JQuery library code. While I can set browser dev tools (I use Edge) not to stop in 3rd party library code when not using the VS Code debugger, I don't see this function in VS Code's debugger.

I have set the **launch.json** file config with:

```
"skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**",
    "code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
]
```

because the debugger reports "code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" as the file it is stopping in, and the "skipFiles" feature is used to inform the debugger on what to ignore. But the debugger is still stopping in the jQuery script.

Looking for way indicate which files the debugger should skip over.